# Looking for slider plugin can use image from url

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider

I need a very simple slider plugin for WordPress that can use images from URL for slider!!
My host space is very low and I couldn't use upload image for my slider , just can use URL for that but couldn't find a plugin that support image from URL !!
I use many images for sliders in my works and I could not upload all of them on my website host!!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try making the slider myself using one of the various jquery sliders available (for example jQuery cycle).

Then us Advanced Custom Fields to create fields with Wordpress where you can paste in the urls of the images you want to use.